# Is it possible to throw an checked Exception implicitly, without any athrow instruction?

Tags: java, exception, checked-exceptions, unchecked-exception

In Java, both checked exception and unchecked exception can be thrown explicitly, i.e, by a `throw` statement. Besides, unchecked exceptions like `ArithmeticException` and `OutOfMemoryError` can be triggered without any explicit `throw` statement like this:

```java
public static void throwArithmeticException() {
    int i = 1;
    int j = i / 0;
}

public static void throwOutOfMemoryError() {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while(true) {
        list.add(new Object());
    }
}
```

So my question is, is there any way to **trigger** an checked Exception, like `IOException`, implicitly, i.e. not using any `throw` statement?

Comment: Is this just purely out of interest/fun or do you have a bigger goal in mind?

Comment: There is no "*`athrow`*" instruction in the java language (it is not even a [keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9)). Also, all `Throwable`s must be `throw`n to have an effect as exception. Otherwise, they are just normal objects. --- For me, the question is unclear. Please [edit] the post and clarify the question.

Comment: @Sweeper My research topic is exception-related, so I am interested in the mechanism of exception handling.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions from @Turing85, I've edited and clarified the question.

Comment: Do you mean "without there being a `throw` anywhere? As in, `Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); Thread.sleep(1);` would result in a checked exception being thrown, but something somewhere is throwing.

Comment: The question is still unclear. Are you talking about bytecode instructions (`athrow`) or java keywords (`throw`)? Please clarify.

Comment: @Turing85 I've removed the declaration of `athrow` instruction. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can do it, but you shouldn't<sup>1</sup>.

I assume that you are talking about the [`athrow` bytecode instruction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.9.athrow).  (And that you *really* asking if you can trigger an exception *from your code* without using a `throw` statement.)

There are (at least) two ways for an application to throw an arbitrary Java exception (checked or unchecked) that don't involve an explicit `athrow` instruction.

1. You can call `Unsafe.throwException(Throwable)`.
2. In native code, you can call the `Throw` or `ThrowNew` functions in the JNI API.

In both cases, you can circumvent the Java (compile time and verifier) checks that are intended to ensure that checked exceptions are always declared (via a `throws` clause) or handled.

Note using `Unsafe` or native code means that your code is not Pure Java.  It won't be portable.  Furthermore it is easy to do things that will make a JVM unstable.  JVM crashes are not unusual.

---

In addition, the JVM will itself throw exceptions without an `athrow` instruction.  For example, if you try to use `new FileInputStream` to open a file that doesn't exist and `FileNotFoundException` is thrown, it is being throw from native code, not from compiled Java code.

It follows that your application can *use* this mechanism to *implicitly* throw many checked and unchecked exceptions; e.g. by *deliberately* trying to open a non-existent file.  However, the method signature for `read` declares that it may throw `IOException`, so the compiler *knows* about this ... from the perspective of the checked exception rules.

---

<sup>1 - And if you application design requires this kind of craziness, you would be advised to come up with an alternative.  It is a bad idea to try to fight Java's checked exception rules.  If you dislike them so much that you are contemplating this, you should pick a different programming language.</sup>

Comment: Why does using `Unsafe` make your code not pure Java? Do you mean in the sense that it is not a "standard" Java API, but a thing specific to JDK implementations?

Comment: Yes.  `Unsafe` is implementation specific in its API.  And on top of that there are all sorts of implementation specific aspects in using `Unsafe` "safely" ... if you get what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

In java bytecode, this is only possible for exceptions the JVM can generate itself, but `IOException` isn't one of them. You can only use the virtual machine to throw a run-time exception which is thrown by interpreting bytecode. For example this code:

```
aconst_null
monitorexit
```

will throw a `NullPointerException`. This is theoretically also possible for throwables like  `NegativeArraySizeException`, `IllegalMonitorStateException`, `WrongMethodTypeException`, `BootstrapMethodError`, `IncompatibleClassChangeError` and many other. You can find out more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html)